# How to add indexed attribute in iPhone Core Data

Tags: iphone, sqlite, core-data

I have a big data to store into three tables in sqlite storage with Core Data. And it works slowly on deletes and inserts. I want add index to improve performance but I don't know how I can do this. Help, please!

Comment: What do you mean by index? did you use Unique ID  for each entry in table?

Comment: I'm not shure( I'm not very strong in core data and model was create by another dev. How can I check it or set it by my self?

Comment: View the core data model by Xcode, and look at the attributes for the entity, and make sure that there is an attribute that describes your entry uniquely

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set index to a field through the **General tab** of **Detail Pane**.
Select the attribute you want to add the index ---> go to general tab of detail pane--->check the check box near **indexed** property.

[image: Attribute detail pane]

Comment: do you have the same issue after trying this ?